# TypeError: this.ExportDataObject is not a function

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, acrobat

I have a simple pdf file containing an embedded file (test.xml) I'm trying to add a JS to call it once the pdf file is opened (even with notification to user to accept the risk etc). I've read that to perform that, the JS that should be used is this:

```
this.ExportDataObject({cName:"test.xml", nLaunch:2});
```

For some reason, it is not working. I checked the debug js console on my Acrobat reader DC (version 2021.001.20145) the the error shown is `TypeError: this.ExportDataObject is not a function`. I'm not sure why on my "this" object the ExportDataObject is not available... I think it should be available always, shouldn't it? I also tested without the `this.` and the error is different `ReferenceError: ExportDataObject is not defined`.

That makes to think to me that `this.ExportDataObject` is existing but is not a function as the original error said... but, if is not a function, what is? a typeof is showing "undefined". Not sure how to make this work. Not sure if next steps should more JS debugging or if the problem is related to something on pdfs or Acrobat. Any help? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript function names are case-sensitive and as [documented](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JS.pdf) by Adobe (p. 151), the correct spelling is `exportDataObject()` without the leading capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you misspelled `ExportDataObject()`

It should be `exportDataObject()`

Using Javascript you should be careful as it is easy to mess up spelling as JS will interpret that in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

As like most of the languages, js is also case sensitive.

But `ReferenceError: ExportDataObject is not defined`, ReferenceError always states that the object is not defined at all, and could'nt be found among the class methods.

so you need to make sure the function with the exact `exportDataObject` name is present and use them accordingly.